# Meteor is stuck at downloading meteor-tool@1.7.0.5

Tags: meteor

When I try to make new meteor project on win 10 it stuck on downloading meteor tools@1.7.0.5 and shows the following line:
downloading meteor-tools@1.7.0.5

How can I troubleshoot this issue? please help

Comment: Kill it and start it again. Build take a long time on Windows, especially when starting with a fresh Meteor install

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10139